# Every bounded monotone sequence converges, most general version

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, reference-request, order-theory

It is a well known fact that in many contexts, [every bounded monotone sequence converges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem).

I wonder what is the most general context where this happens. That is,

> Let $X$ be a set equipped with a topology and with a partial order. Let $(x_\lambda)_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ be a monotone net (i.e. $x_\lambda\le x_\mu$ if $\lambda\le\mu$), bounded in the sense that for all $\lambda$ we have that $x_\lambda\le y$ for some fixed $y\in X$. Under which additional conditions can we conclude that $(x_\lambda)$ converges?

One such condition is for example that $X$ is compact. Obviously this is not the most general case. Is there an established theory about these facts?

Comment: There is "(order) complete" lattice, where all subsets have a sup and inf.  There is "conditionally complete" lattice where all subsets that are bounded above have a sup.  There is the setting used for Zorn's lemma, where every chain has an upper bound.  But none of these is exactly what is proposed here.